# How do I convert a signed 16-bit hexadecimal to decimal?

Tags: r, hex, decimal, type-conversion, signed

I have a very long sequence of data stored as unsigned 16-bit PCM (it's audio). Using Frhed, I can view the file as hex. I'd like to convert the hex into decimal. So far I've exported into a csv file and attempted to convert in R using `as.integer()`. However, this doesn't seem to take into account that the values are signed.

Comment: Not my downvote. Have you tried   `strtoi(x, base = 16L)` ?

Comment: @G5W, post as answer?

Comment: OK,  I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert hex text strings to decimal digits using `strtoi`. You will need to specify that the base is 16.

```
HexData = c("A167", "AE8F", "6A99", "0966", "784D", "A637", "102D", "4521")
strtoi(HexData, base=16L)
[1] 41319 44687 27289  2406 30797 42551  4141 17697
```

This is assuming unsigned data. Your question mentions both signed and unsigned so I am not quite sure which you have.